# Coverting from Decimal Type Unit to Architectural

Tags: autodesk

I have been using feet as units for my layout under the decimal length type.

Ex: 4'8" length wall would be inputted as 4.667'.

I just realized that there is an architectural type for length units. Is there any way I can convert from decimal to architectural type while still using feet as my units? Currently, when I try to do this, my 91.607' by 38.333' room (decimal type) is converted to 7' - 5/8" by 3' - 2 5/16" (architectural length type).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use the following steps:

1. dimstyle
2. modify
3. switch to architectural

architectural should use feet where fractional would keep it as inches. Also make sure your units are set to inches in your actual file (command units).